# "can" middleware doesn't work for multi-domains in laravel

Tags: laravel-9

I declared a "Gate" like this:

```
Gate::define('isAdmin', fn (\App\Models\User $user) => true);
```

in "AuthServiceProvider" and called that like this:

```
        //dashboard subdomains injection
    Route::middleware(['web', 'auth', 'can:isAdmin'])  <----------------
        ->domain('dashboard.khassepaz.test')
        ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));

    //blog subdomains injection
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->domain('blog.khassepaz.test')
        ->group(base_path('routes/blog.php'));

    //normal domains
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->domain('khassepaz.test')
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

but when I try to go to "dashboard.khassepaz.test", it redirects to the login page since I have already logged in, I am redirected to the home page that is defined in "RouteServiceProvider" in the "HOME" constant. http://khassepaz.test/

where is my mistake? please help.

NOTE: For information, the user has already registered

UPDATE: public const HOME = '/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to config/session.php and change

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),
```

to

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.maindomain.com'),
```

now the authenticated user is identified over the main domain and all over subdomains.